# Angularjs Replace `#` with `w` or with something else

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In angular js urls are start with `#`. I want to change `#` with some character, however i know we can remove `#` with `html5Mode(true)`. But i don't want to remove it , i just need to replace it with some other character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually change the fragment identifier (`#`).
It's used in Angular for identifying the resource route.

You could use `html5Mode` in order to delete it only in browsers that support that kind of behavior. in other browsers that doesn't support this behavior, Angular has a fallback guarantee, that it will change the route to start with `#!`.